# Loop to create or update nodes in Neo4j

Tags: javascript, neo4j

I am new to Neo4j so I quite stuck with looping through some values.

I have a list of skill to skill strings

```
let data = [
  'big_data, business_intelligence',
  'big_data, data_collection',
  'big_data, economic_growth',
  'big_data, economy'
]
```

And I want to create or update the relation between left side with right side

```
for (let item of data) {
    CreateSkillToSkillRelation(item);
}

const CreateSkillToSkillRelation = async (relation) => {
  let mainSkill = relation.split(",")[0];
  let secundarySkill = relation.split(",")[1];

  try {
    // Check if the relationship exists
    let { records } = await session.run(
      "MATCH(main:SKILL {name:$mainSkill}) -[relation:SKILL_TO_SKILL]-> (secundary:SKILL {name:$secundarySkill}) RETURN relation",
      { mainSkill, secundarySkill }
    );

    let count =
      records[0]?._fields[0].properties.count > 0
        ? records[0]._fields[0].properties.count + 1
        : 1;

    // If count is greater then 1 then lets update the counter
    if (count > 1) {
      await session.run(
        "MATCH(main:SKILL {name:$mainSkill}) -[relation:SKILL_TO_SKILL]-> (secundary:SKILL {name:$secundarySkill}) SET relation.count = $count RETURN main, secundary",
        {
          mainSkill,
          secundarySkill,
          count,
        }
      );
    }
    // Otherwise the skill relation is not created so lets create one
    else {
      await session.run(
        "CREATE(main:SKILL {name:$mainSkill}) -[:SKILL_TO_SKILL {count:$count}]-> (secundary:SKILL {name:$secundarySkill}) RETURN main, secundary",
        {
          mainSkill,
          secundarySkill,
          count,
        }
      );
    }

    await session.close();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

But every time when I run this I get the following error `Neo4jError: Queries cannot be run directly on a session with an open transaction; either run from within the transaction or use a different session.`

Any idea how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (let item of data) {
    CreateSkillToSkillRelation(item);
}
```

Is not awaiting the promises you create and so you are basically trying to run all of these promises concurrently against a single session which only supports a single concurrent transaction.

You should create a session in each call of `CreateSkillToSkillRelation` or await each call to it using a single session.

Though note you close the session at the end of `CreateSkillToSkillRelation` but only on success, might I suggest moving `await session.close();` into a finally block.

Answer (score 0):

1. The answer of the colleague [@just_another_dotnet_dev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72859125/4989460) is absolutely correct: you run asynchronous functions in a loop, and close the session in one of them.
2. The Cipher language is very rich, and you can use it to do everything that you tried to do with a loop in Javascript. Something like this, using [`UNWIND`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/unwind/#unwind-unwinding-a-list) and [`MERGE`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/#merge-merge-with-on-create):

---

```
const CreateSkillToSkillRelations = async (data) => {
  const session = driver.session();
  try {
    let { records } = await session.run(
        `WITH split(row, ',') as rels
         WITH trim(rels[0]) as mainSkill, 
              trim(rels[1]) as secundarySkill
         MERGE (main:SKILL {name: mainSkill})
               -[relation:SKILL_TO_SKILL]->
               (secundary:SKILL {name: secundarySkill})
           ON CREATE SET relation.count = 1
           ON MATCH SET relation.count = relation.count + 1
         RETURN main, relation, secundary`,
         { data }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await session.close()
  }
};
```